# How to fix ESLint "require is not defined" when it is used in just one file?

Tags: javascript, eslint, eslintrc

When I use `require` in my JavaScript, I get a warning from eslint, "require is not defined eslint(no-undef)".

Except for this one file, all the files in my project uses the browser `env`, which is set in my `.eslintrc`.

How can I make an exception and specify a node env for just this one file?

```js
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

// my code
```

Answer (score 10):

Similar to how you can override eslint rules with a code comment at the top of the file, you can also override the environment:

```js
/* eslint-env node */

var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

// my code
```

Setting the node environment will make it so that node features like `require` and `__dirname` are not treated as undefined.

See [Specifying Environments](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-environments) in the eslint documentation.